# Filling a custom RelativeLayout with an ImageView and not surpassing its limits

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to create an object to populate a listview so that if i pass it a certain image, it fills its limits not surpassing the region its defined on. In order to do that, i have created a drawable file so if i reference it as background, my relativelayout converts into a round shape. The problem is that with my local images, there is not problem apparently or at least the designer does not show any problem filling it.
This is how i want each item to look like for any image dimension:

[Ideal image shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp01o.png)

But whenever i try to fill it with an external image,located in firebase, the image surpasses this shape and just fill the entire region defined by the relative layout, displaying it like this:

[How it looks atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gklTh.jpg)

I have tried many different imageview settings after defining the cliptooutline in the relativelayout, height, width, scale type or even giving it the background of the shape already defined. Could someone help me correct my xml or finding a method to making my code behave as expected please?

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/event_shape"
        android:clipToOutline="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/evento_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/evento_banner"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/event_shape">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/evento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Evento"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechainicio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="20/10/2023"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ratingstar"
            android:text="4,7"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ratingstar"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_star_24" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lineaseparacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locationicon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_location_on_24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/localizacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/locationicon"
            android:text="Madrid"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechafin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="27/10/2023"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/precio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="Gratis"
            android:textColor="#4CAF50"
            android:textSize="14sp">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The background shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#9C27B0">
            </solid>
            <stroke android:color="@color/black"
                android:width="1dp">
            </stroke>
            <corners android:radius="50dp">
            </corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/grey">
            </solid>
            <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"
                android:width="2dp">
            </stroke>
            <corners android:radius="50dp">
            </corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Update: following the first answer, i have tried using a cardview, but even after adapting it to get the same preview, the image surpasses the cardview region. Is there a way to adapt the xml or at least adapt the image on the backend of the section so it doesnt surpass the region defined?

Comment: IMHO I would just do a CardView with an ImageView inside it. give it radius, and set padding to 0dp.  if you use Material CardView  you have more options to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you want something like then following [image]

If so update your xml with the following,

** Please not that I used a background color instead of an image, in your case use `android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"`.
I have tried it and it works with image too

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- give a desired cardCornerRadius to CardView -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

    <!-- margin and padding to 0dp (may not be neccessary) -->
    <!-- I also have not included the image here. I just used a background color -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/evento_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:margin ="0dp"
        android:padding = "0dp"
        android:background="@color/Neon"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/lightGrey"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/super_lightGrey"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/evento"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="Evento"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechainicio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="20/10/2023"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ratingstar"
                android:text="4,7"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ratingstar"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lineaseparacion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/locationicon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/settings" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/localizacion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/locationicon"
                android:text="Madrid"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechafin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="27/10/2023"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/precio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="Gratis"
                android:textColor="#4CAF50"
                android:textSize="14sp">

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: After setting hardware accelerated, the solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- give a desired cardCornerRadius to CardView -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <!-- margin and padding to 0dp (may not be neccessary) -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/evento_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:margin ="0dp"
            android:padding = "0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/evento_banner"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<!-- rest of your tags -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope some thing like this is what you are looking for

Comment: I have tried your solution but sadly the image still fills the entire layout and does not adjust to the corners :(

Comment: @TheMetagame Have you closed the tags correctly? please look at the second answer for a complete layout file.